# Запись содержимого файла в переменную JavaScript

Tags: javascript, файлы

мне нужна помощь.
Есть JS функция:

```
function generate() {
var a = "some"
return(a)
}
```

Мне нужно что бы в переменную `a` попало содержимое файла `file.txt`, т.е. функция возращала бы полное содержание файла.
Подскажите как это сделать.

Comment: А где этот файл и где мы выполняем скрипт?

Comment: @AlexeyTen скрипт выполняется на сайте, файл лежит в той же директории что и скрипт

Comment: воспользуйтесь fetch или xmlhttprequest

Comment: @Allespro JS скрипт обычно выполняется на клиенте (если это не серверный скрипт Node.js) а на клиенте никаких файлов, лежащих на сервере нет. Что бы его получить надо его с сервера запросить. Делается это обычно методами ajax. (тот же xmlhttprequest, о котором сказали выше). Только в переменную ни один из методов напрямую внутри функции, такой как вы написали, получить его нельзя. Функция отправит запрос на сервер, js продолжит выполнение и функция завершиться, а позже произойдет событие готовности данных и вот в его обработчике у вас в переменной будет ответ сервера (файл)